# Cant get Yii Model custom rules to work

Tags: php, yii

In a form i working on, i have this rules set which i want to validate. **rate** should be a a floating number. and **price** should be numbers with `,` and `.`

here is what i have so far

```
public function rules()
{
    array('rate','type', 'type'=>'float', 'on' => 'loan-calculator'),

    // EPriceValidator is a custom validation class
    array('price', 'site.common.components.validate.EPriceValidator'),
}
```

In **site.common.components.validate.EPriceValidator** i have this

```
class EPriceValidator extends CRegularExpressionValidator
{
        public $pattern = '/[^0-9,.]/';
}
```

when i change

```
array('price', 'site.common.components.validate.EPriceValidator'),
```

to

```
array('price', 'match', 'not' => true, 'pattern' => '/[^0-9,.]/'),
```

it works perfectly when validating on the fly. but i would rather put it into a class, this way i can reuse it thru out my site.

```
array('rate','type', 'type'=>'float', 'on' => 'loan-calculator'),
```

the code above on the other hand doesn't work at all. Any idea how i can fix these two problems? Or what am i'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: is the path problem to the validation? try this: array('price', 'application.components.validate.EPriceValidator'),

Comment: the path `site.common.components.validate.EPriceValidator` is correct. and the file does exist in the folder

Comment: @user2636556 You forgot `public $not = true;` in your validator. As for the `rate` validator, the only thing I can think of would be that you are not correctly specifying the scenario when you create the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
class EPriceValidator extends CValidator
{

    //Regular Expressions for numbers
    private $pattern = '/[^0-9,.]/';

     //Default error messages 
     private $err_msg = '{attribute} is an invalid.';

    /**
     * Validates the attribute of the object.
     * If there is any error, the error message is added to the object.
     * @param CModel $object the object being validated
     * @param string $attribute the attribute being validated
     */
    protected function validateAttribute($object,$attribute)
    {
        $pattern = $this->pattern;

        // extract the attribute value from it's model object
        $value = $object->$attribute;

        if(!preg_match($pattern, $value))
        {
            $this->addError($object, $attribute, $this->err_msg);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Implementing Client Validation
     *
     * Returns the JavaScript needed for performing client-side validation.
     * @param CModel $object the data object being validated
     * @param string $attribute the name of the attribute to be validated.
     * @return string the client-side validation script.
     * @see CActiveForm::enableClientValidation
     */
    public function clientValidateAttribute($object,$attribute)
    {

        // check the strength parameter used in the validation rule of our model
        $pattern = $this->pattern; 

        //replace {attribute} with correct label
        $params['{attribute}']=$object->getAttributeLabel($attribute);
        $error_message = strtr($this->err_msg,$params);

        return "
        if(value.match(".$pattern.")) {
            messages.push(".CJSON::encode($error_message).");
        }
        ";
    }
}
```

the `validateAttribute()` function overrides the CValidator class function for server side validation. And the `clientValidateAttribute()` function overrides the CValidator class function for client side validation.

for more information [read this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CValidator)